# How can I execute random results in c++ as the code given below?

Tags: c++

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 int main(){
     int results[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
     cout << results << endl;
     return 0;
 }
```

I want **different** result each time.
for example: first time 1 second time 2 etc.
Any help?

Comment: "Different", as in [random](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random)?

Comment: `std::shuffle` might be of use.

Comment: Do you want a to returns an item in sequece each time (eg 1,2,3,4,5) or do you want random selection from `results` ?

Comment: Example is given I don't even know what rand() is. And how it is used

Comment: And now you know how it's called, you can read how to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One easy way is to seed the basic random number generator with the current time then use [rand()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand) reduced modulo the number of possible results to choose a random element from `results`

```
#include "iostream"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int results[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    srand(time(NULL));
    cout << results[rand()%(sizeof(results)/sizeof(results[0]))] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The same code is giving me error...

Comment: What does this line means: `srand(time(NULL));`

Comment: @RanaFaizAhmed I was missing an include for `<ctime>` - I've added this now.  `srand(time(NULL))` takes the current time and uses it to seed the random number generator.  Despite its name, this actually generates a very long but predictable stream of numbers.  By varying the seed, we vary the point at which we start in this stream, achieving an effect that is close enough to random for your needs.

Comment: Can we use this code for strings not integers?

Comment: You could use this approach for an array of any type.

Comment: Your welcome.  Since you're a new user, I hope you don't mind if I point you towards this link on [accepting answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234).  If your question is now answered, you could accept one of the answers here.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this. You have to seed the random number with for example the integer respresenting the current time. Because if you don't call srand, the program will continue to shuffle the array excactly the same way each time. Therefore, some programs even log theire seed, so they can run the program with the same random values. Be carefull that code requires you compile with an c++11 compatible compiler. On my system time(0) gives me the numbe of seconds since januari first 1970. Therefore the output of my program will give me different results every time.

Also note since if the seed is the same, you'll alway get the same shuffle. Therefore although you'll will get different shuffling each second, the result are predicatable given the value of `time(0)` and to get really high quality random numbers (and thus random shuffling ) you have to do something even more unpredictable.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


int main (){

    std::srand(time(0));
    std::vector<int> vec = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
    std::random_shuffle( vec.begin(), vec.end() );
    for ( int i = 0; i < vec.size();  i++)
        std::cout << vec[i]<< std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```