# Can someone explain this line of c++?

Tags: c++

```
cout << results[rand()%(sizeof(results)/sizeof(results[0]))] << endl;
```

results is an array of integers: 1,2,3,4,5.
Can somebody Explain?

Comment: If you have an array like `int results[10]`, then `sizeof(results)/sizeof(results[0])` will give you `10`. Then `rand()` mod that will be between `0` and `9`, which is used as an index into that array of 10 elements (0 being the first and 9 being the last).

Comment: This line selects a random index entry from the `results` array or vector for output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20741902/311966) was a bit terse...

```
cout << results[rand()%(sizeof(results)/sizeof(results[0]))] << endl;
```

could be broken down to

```
int num_elems = sizeof(results)/sizeof(results[0]);
int randomIndex = rand() % num_elems;
int randomValue = results[randomIndex];
cout << randomValue << endl;
```

In slightly more detail:

- `sizeof(results)/sizeof(results[0])` calculates the number of elements in the array `results`.  (Note that this only works when you have access to the array definition - you can't use this with a pointer to an array.)
- `rand() % num_elems` calculates a random number in the range [0..num_elems-1]; this is the range of the `results` array.
- `results[randomIndex]` returns a single, randomly selected, element from `results`

Answer (score 1):

This will print the value of your arrayentry in a random order.

It creates a random value and limits it to the index of the arraysize by using the modulo operator `%`.

`rand()` create a random integer value in the range of `0 to RAND_MAX`

`sizeof(results)/sizeof(results[0])` is the size of your array as you defined it earlier in your code i.e. `int results[5]`

The modulo operator `%` combines those tww values and makes sure that the result is not bigger then the size of your array (0-4).

Comment: I know that, I just wanna know this line in detail. Please. Can you?

Comment: @RanaFaizAhmed, Updated with more detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

`rand()` returns a random number.

You want a random number from the array that is of size 5. So you use the [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operator to be sure that you're not exceeding 4 (0,1,2,3 or 4).

`sizeof(results)` returns the total size in bytes of the array. `sizeof(results[0])` is the size of an element in that array. For example, if `sizeof(results[0])` is 8, then `sizeof(results)` is 40, so the result will be 40/8 which is 5, which is the array's size.